# Android Google Maps GroundOverlay from Bitmap appears white

Tags: android, google-maps, bitmap

I am trying to display a ground overlay downloaded from url.

the problem is that the image is not shown and the overlay appears as white square.

thinking the Bitmap Object is faulty i tested:

1. addding the same bitmap Object to a marker -  the marker shows o.k
2. get an image with `.fromResource(R.id.myimage)` - the overlay shows o.k

but my image is from downloaded Bitmap Object.

This is my code:

```
private void addOverlayFromBitmap(Bitmap bmImage){
        BitmapDescriptor image = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmImage);
        //image = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.radaraimage9);

        //Set Anchors
        LatLng NE_ANCHOR = new LatLng(34.516481,37.679488);
        LatLng SW_ANCHOR = new LatLng(29.474814,31.876530);

        //Set Bounds
        LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds(SW_ANCHOR,NE_ANCHOR);

        // Append Overlay to map - image appears as white square
        map.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
             .image(image)
             .positionFromBounds(bounds)
             .transparency((float) 0.5));

        //add marker for debugging - image appears fine
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(NORTH_EAST_ANCHOR)
                .icon(image)
                );
}
```

The AsyncTask:

```
private class LoadRadarImageryTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    Bitmap bmImage;

    public LoadRadarImageryTask() {
        super();
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String url = urls[0];
        Bitmap image = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
            image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return image;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image) {
        addOverlayFromBitmap(image);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be a problem of using large images means higher resolution. It could be suggested by your log cat so can you paste your log cat here.

OR

Try using Tile Overlay instead of ground overlay.

OR

use this code which worked for me in same problem..

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.util.TypedValue;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;





    public class MapDisplayActivity extends FragmentActivity implements         OnMapClickListener, OnMapLongClickListener  {
    private GoogleMap myMap;

    private static  LatLng SearchPlace;
    double Latitude;
    double Longitiude;
    List<Address> addresses;

    //Address location;
    BitmapDescriptor image;
/// private static final LatLng NEWARK = new LatLng(18.5236, 73.8478);


        private GroundOverlay mGroundOverlay;

        //this is for omnistarg dont touch this 
        LatLng southwest= new LatLng(-85.513398,-178.242187);

        LatLng northeast= new LatLng(85.513398,178.242187);

     float zoomValue = 7.0f;
    private String SpinerValue;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
        @Override
        `enter code here`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mapactivity);
    //VMRuntime.getRuntime().setMinimumHeapSize(4 * 1024 * 1024);
    Log.v("Utils", "Max mem in MB : " +    (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/(1024*1024)));
    Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
    Debug.getNativeHeapSize();

    initActionBar();

    //textInfo=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.locinfo);

       FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
       SupportMapFragment mySupportMapFragment 
        = (SupportMapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
       myMap = mySupportMapFragment.getMap();





      // myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


      // myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
       myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
      // myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
       //myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);


       myMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
       myMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
       myMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
       myMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

       Intent intent=getIntent();
       Latitude=intent.getDoubleExtra("Latitude", 0.000);
       Longitiude=intent.getDoubleExtra("Longititude", 0.000);
       SpinerValue=(String)intent.getStringExtra("SPINNERVALUE");

       SearchPlace = new LatLng(Latitude, Longitiude);

       myMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(SearchPlace));
       myMap.addMarker(new   MarkerOptions().position(SearchPlace));//.title(PlaceName));
       drawImageOverMap();




}



public void drawImageOverMap(){

       myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(zoomValue));

            //image =BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.omnistar_g);
       if(SpinerValue.equalsIgnoreCase("TEC")){
           //centerpoint_vrs
           bitmap =   (Bitmap)BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.omnistar_two);


            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
             o2.inSampleSize=4;
             image=BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
                LatLngBounds bounds =new LatLngBounds( southwest,  northeast);


                mGroundOverlay  = myMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
                    .image(image)
                    //.transparency(0.4f)

                    //.anchor(0, 1)
                    .positionFromBounds(bounds));

       }
       else if(SpinerValue.equalsIgnoreCase("OmniSTARG2")){
           bitmap = (Bitmap)BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.omnistar_g_img);


            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
             o2.inSampleSize=4;
             image=BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
                LatLngBounds bounds =new LatLngBounds( southwest,  northeast);


                mGroundOverlay  = myMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
                    .image(image)
                    .transparency(0.4f)

                    //.anchor(0, 1)
                    .positionFromBounds(bounds));
       }
       else if(SpinerValue.equalsIgnoreCase("OmniStarHP")){
           bitmap = (Bitmap)BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.omnistar_hp_two);


            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
             o2.inSampleSize=4;
             image=BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
                LatLngBounds bounds =new LatLngBounds( southwest,  northeast);


                mGroundOverlay  = myMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
                    .image(image)
                    .transparency(0.4f)

                    //.anchor(0, 1)
                    .positionFromBounds(bounds));
       }
       /////////////////////////////////////////////
       else if(SpinerValue.equalsIgnoreCase("OmniStarVBS")){
           bitmap = (Bitmap)BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.omnistar_vbs_two);


            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
             o2.inSampleSize=4;
             image=BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
                LatLngBounds bounds =new LatLngBounds( southwest,  northeast);


                mGroundOverlay  = myMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
                    .image(image)
                    .transparency(0.4f)

                    //.anchor(0, 1)
                    .positionFromBounds(bounds));

       }
       else if(SpinerValue.equalsIgnoreCase("OmniSTARXP")){
           bitmap = (Bitmap)BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.omnistar_xp_two);


            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
             o2.inSampleSize=4;
             image=BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
                LatLngBounds bounds =new LatLngBounds( southwest,  northeast);


                mGroundOverlay  = myMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
                    .image(image)
                    .transparency(0.4f)

                    //.anchor(0, 1)
                    .positionFromBounds(bounds));
       }
       else if(SpinerValue.equalsIgnoreCase("RTXStandardviaCellular")){
          //rtxcell 
           bitmap = (Bitmap)BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.rtx_cell_two);


            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
             o2.inSampleSize=4;
             image=BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
                LatLngBounds bounds =new LatLngBounds( southwest,  northeast);


                mGroundOverlay  = myMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
                    .image(image)
                    .transparency(0.3f)

                    //.anchor(0, 1)
                    .positionFromBounds(bounds));
       }
       else if(SpinerValue.equalsIgnoreCase("RTXFastviaSatellite")){
           //rtxfast.png
           bitmap = (Bitmap)BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.rtx_fast_two);


            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
             o2.inSampleSize=4;
             image=BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
                LatLngBounds bounds =new LatLngBounds( southwest,  northeast);


                mGroundOverlay  = myMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
                    .image(image)
                    .transparency(0.3f)

                    //.anchor(0, 1)
                    .positionFromBounds(bounds));
       }
       else if(SpinerValue.equalsIgnoreCase("RTXStandardviaSatellite")){
           //rtxsat.png
           bitmap = (Bitmap)BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.rtx_sat_two);


            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
             o2.inSampleSize=4;
             image=BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
                LatLngBounds bounds =new LatLngBounds( southwest,  northeast);


                mGroundOverlay  = myMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
                    .image(image)
                    .transparency(0.3f)

                    //.anchor(0, 1)
                    .positionFromBounds(bounds));
       }
       else if(SpinerValue.equalsIgnoreCase("VRSNow")){
           //vrsnowtec.png
           bitmap = (Bitmap)BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.vrsnow_tec_two);


            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
             o2.inSampleSize=4;
             image=BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
                LatLngBounds bounds =new LatLngBounds( southwest,  northeast);


                mGroundOverlay  = myMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
                    .image(image)
                    .transparency(0.3f)

                    //.anchor(0, 1)
                    .positionFromBounds(bounds));
       }
                    // InputStream is =getClass().getResourceAsStream(omnistar_g);
                    //bitmap = readAssetsBitmap("omnistar_g.png");
                     //bitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.trimble_screen_logo);
                     //bitmap=bitmap(is);


                     //image =BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.omnistar_g);


                             bitmap.recycle();
                             bitmap = null;
                             System.gc();
                             Runtime.getRuntime().gc(); 



}
```

Comment: The target image is GIF 512x512 and when saved to pc its size is 100kb.

Comment: is that too large? , i didn't find anything in the log and have problems with printing it, but when trying on android icon (size of 4kb) it works.  is there another option rather than TileOverlay?

Comment: i am sure this is the problem of large images because its working with small size icon. what is the problem to move to tile overlays? and if you don't want to move see my edit.